# Folder missing inside docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I wrote [this](https://github.com/mictadlo/mGSV-docker) docker-compose project. The [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/mictadlo/mGSV-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) looks like this:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mgsv
      - MYSQL_USER=mgsv_user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mgsvpass
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysql123
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

  www:
    build: ./mGSV 
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

And the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/mictadlo/mGSV-docker/blob/master/mGSV/Dockerfile) is based on a PHP container and looks like this.

```
FROM php:5-apache

RUN apt-get update  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
                openjdk-7-jdk \
                maven  \
        git \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN git clone https://github.com/qunfengdong/mGSV.git

# Move the folder 'mgsv' to DocumentRoot of Apache web server. By default, the DocumentRoot of Apache is /var/www/ (speak to the system administrator to know the exact DocumentRoot).
RUN cd /var/www/html/mGSV \
    && mkdir tmp \
    && chmod -R 777 tmp

RUN cd /var/www/html/mGSV && sed -i.bak "s|'gsv'|'mgsv_user'|" lib/settings.php \ 
    && sed -i.bak "s|$database_pass = ''|$database_pass = 'mgsvpass'|" lib/settings.php \
    && sed -i.bak "s|cas-qshare.cas.unt.edu|localhost|" lib/settings.php

RUN cp /var/www/html/mGSV/Arial.ttf /usr/share/fonts/truetype/

RUN cd /var/www/html/mGSV/ws \
    && tar -xzf mgsv-ws-server.tar.gz

RUN cd /var/www/html/mGSV/ws/mgsv-ws-server \ 
    && mvn package

RUN cp -f /var/www/html/mGSV/ws/mgsv-ws-server/target/ws-server-1.0RC1-jar-with-dependencies.jar /var/www/html/mGSV/ws/

RUN cd /var/www/html/mGSV/ws \ 
    && echo "mgsv_upload_url=http://localhost/mgsv" > config.properties \
    && echo "ws_publish_url=http\://localhost\:8081/MGSVService" >> config.properties \
    && java -jar ws-server-1.0RC1-jar-with-dependencies.jar &
```

This is the output which I got:

```
Step 1/11 : FROM php:5-apache
 ---> 8f4a38cf4542
Step 2/11 : RUN apt-get update  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends                 openjdk-7-jdk                 maven       git         && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f194797b9362
Step 3/11 : RUN git clone https://github.com/qunfengdong/mGSV.git
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4acd066da444
Step 4/11 : RUN cd /var/www/html/mGSV     && mkdir tmp     && chmod -R 777 tmp
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f766f9ceb7d3
Step 5/11 : RUN cd /var/www/html/mGSV && sed -i.bak "s|'gsv'|'mgsv_user'|" lib/settings.php     && sed -i.bak "s|$database_pass = ''|$database_pass = 'mgsvpass'|" lib/settings.php     && sed -i.bak "s|cas-qshare.cas.unt.edu|localhost|" lib/settings.php
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 007dff8907f4
Step 6/11 : RUN cp /var/www/html/mGSV/Arial.ttf /usr/share/fonts/truetype/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 026049ca32d8
Step 7/11 : RUN cd /var/www/html/mGSV/ws     && tar -xzf mgsv-ws-server.tar.gz
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 92a0f85b27a0
Step 8/11 : RUN cd /var/www/html/mGSV/ws/mgsv-ws-server     && mvn package
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5aa1723f255f
Step 9/11 : RUN cp -f /var/www/html/mGSV/ws/mgsv-ws-server/target/ws-server-1.0RC1-jar-with-dependencies.jar /var/www/html/mGSV/ws/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f0dbd0ac1ddb
Step 10/11 : RUN cd /var/www/html/mGSV/ws     && echo "mgsv_upload_url=http://localhost/mgsv" > config.properties     && echo "ws_publish_url=http\://localhost\:8081/MGSVService" >> config.properties     && java -jar ws-server-1.0RC1-jar-with-dependencies.jar &
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0c86c0adddd5
```

However, when I create an interactive session the `/var/www/html/` is empty:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                             TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
php                                    5-apache            8f4a38cf4542        7 days ago          374MB

$ sudo docker run --entrypoint /bin/bash -i -t 8f4a38cf4542
root@a3908e297bcf:/var/www/html# ls
```

Why can't I see the `/var/www/html/mGSV` folder inside the docker container?

Thank you in advance.

Michal

Comment: before `RUN git clone https://github.com/qunfengdong/mGSV.git`  do `RUN cd /var/www/html/` first.

Comment: I changed it to `RUN cd /var/www/html/ && git clone https://github.com/qunfengdong/mGSV.git` but when I log in `mGSV `folder is still missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `8f4a38cf4542` image is the `php:5-apache` base image you are building `FROM` before all your additions.

The `docker-compose` build output should include a line: `Successfully built eccdcc9a9534` at the end, which is the image ID you need to copy from your output and use. You should be able to find this image in the complete output:

```
docker images -a
```

To make life easier, add an `image` name to the `www` service so compose tags the build and it's easily accessable:

```
www:
  build: ./mGSV
  image: user3523406/www
  restart: always
```

Then

```
sudo docker run --entrypoint /bin/bash -it user3523406/www
```